# Prevent 500 Internal Server Error when serving lots of photos via a PHP thumbnailing library

Tags: php, apache, webserver, http-status-codes

I have a website that allows users to contribute (upload) photos to albums.

In order to protect the photos, they are stored in a folder outside `/public_html` and displayed in pages through a script called [PHPThumb](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb) which displays small resized versions of the photos with lower quality (since high-resolution photos may be uploaded), and also allows users to add their watermark to the photos.

My issue is that sometimes when there's a lot of traffic to a specific album (page), some photos do not show up, or the whole page shows a `500 Internal Server Error` altogether (even though I use pagination and show only 40 photos per page). It takes a few seconds, or sometimes minutes before the site comes back.

I thought that using a thumbnailing library would lessen the load because the server doesn't have to send the whole high-resolution photos, but only the resized versions. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

I am using a shared web hosting package, and while I do know that shared is not recommended for my web app, I would like to explore any other options to improve the site, before I decide to upgrade my web hosting package.

Any suggestions on preventing the `500` error?

Would also accept suggestions for a good web host, given the setup described above. (I am not very well-versed with server administration.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Those thumbnails are not generated on the fly on each request and they are cached, right ? If not, you could start from there.
2. Storing the original image outside of public directory makes sense, but you could consider storing the thumbnails inside a public directory so you could serve them directly, without processing.
3. Also make sure that you send the correct cache headers when you serve those thumbnails. Considering that a thumbnail is a small replica of a bigger version, it will not change, so you could set the expiration date very far ahead.

   3.1 However, in your case you let the user to put a watermark on thumbnails, so you could cache your thumbnails based on that watermark. You could hash the image name + watermark and get a thumbnail name. If the watermark will change, also the thumbnail name will be different, so the "far ahead" cache expiration headers will not bite you.